# Why is my TypeScript property complaining that it might be undefined when I've already added a check?

Tags: typescript

```ts
const handleClick = (index: number) => () => {
  const hasUrl = !!searchTypes[index]?.url
  if (hasUrl) {
    router.push(searchTypes[index]?.url);
  } else {
    setSelectedSearchType(index);
  }
};
```

But the error I'm getting is:

```
(property) url?: string | undefined
Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Url'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Url'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can also just put a `!` at the end of a variable definition and it forces the type to not be undefined.

```
const url = searchTypes[index]?.url!
```

Answer (score 3):

Because TypeScript cannot<sup>1</sup> infer from the usage of the `hasUrl` variable back to the existence of the property. Prefer to write

```
const handleClick = (index: number) => () => {
  const url = searchTypes[index]?.url
  if (url) {
    router.push(url);
  } else {
    setSelectedSearchType(index);
  }
};
```

<sub>1: meaning it's not implemented in the compiler, not that it would be impossible. The `!!` makes it extra hard though.</sub>